# ipv6, static for some destinations, dynamic for the rest

Tags: ipv6, dynamic-ip

I would like to use a static ipv6 when accessing the company network (from other locations, eg home) and dynamic (privacy) adresses for the rest of the internet.

Is that possible? Does this relate to prefixpolicy?

The machines are windows 7,8,freebsd and linux'es

Answer (score 1):

I know that on Linux you can do this with an explicit route to the company network addresses. Say that `2001:db8:1234::/48` is your company network, `2001:db8:abcd::1` the gateway to that address space (or maybe your default gateway) and `2001:db8:abcd::8` the fixed local address you want to use, then this will do it:

```
ip -6 route add 2001:db8:1234::/48 via 2001:db8:abcd::1 src 2001:db8:abcd::8
```

Other traffic will use the default route, and unless that one has a `src ...` attached to it too it will use the normal source address selection rules and use temporary/privacy addresses.